# How do I divide a Numpy array along axis-0 into a list of equal sized numpy arrays where the goal number of sub-arrays can be any value?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

For example array x,  `np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])`

Divided into 3 "folds" along axis-0 would be like  `[array([[1, 2, 3, 4]]), array([[5, 6, 7, 8]]), array([[ 9, 10, 11, 12]]` in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])

In [3]: np.array_split(a, 3)
Out[3]: [array([[1, 2, 3, 4]]), array([[5, 6, 7, 8]]), array([[ 9, 10, 11, 12]])]
```

axis=0 is the default, you can specify another axis as well

```
In [4]: np.array_split(a, 4, axis=1)
Out[4]:
[array([[1],
        [5],
        [9]]), array([[ 2],
        [ 6],
        [10]]), array([[ 3],
        [ 7],
        [11]]), array([[ 4],
        [ 8],
        [12]])]
```

Comment: Hello karafka. Thank you very much for your answer. How would I do this same exact process but with the added requirement of equal-sized sub-arrays. To achieve this, some of the values in the original array may not be used in these sub-arrays.

Comment: @NicholasFowlkes not sure I understand what you mean.  It's a rectangular matrix and splitting to rows will have equal number of elements.  Perhaps you mean something else and may justify a new question with test input and expected output.

Comment: I agree, I have posted a new question with new test input and output.